# How is a lay person supposed to ever attain Nibbana?

Tags: nirvana

The Buddha said in an indirect way that if one practices consistently for 7 days, enlightenment is guaranteed. My question is if there are thousands of monks who live in monasteries and practice all day everyday who aren't enlightened, how on earth is an ordinary lay person supposed to attain it?

Comment: "So are you saying we are all stuck here forever?". That's the problem. (we are all stuck here forever) Buddha teaches us how to be free from it forever.

Comment: practices consistently for 7 days? Only if [ you have normal level intellect(or higher) ] + [ will to give your 100% in all 7 days(which a lot of people lack) ] + [ learn what to do in that 7 days correctly before starting(also a lot of people don't get) ] + [ enough good karma(Not have done very bad karma in this or old(near past) lives) ]

Answer (score 4):

I presumed that you are referring to the Buddha’s words in [Satipatthana Sutta](https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/MN/MN10.html).

> Let alone half a month. If anyone would develop these four establishings of mindfulness in this way for seven days, one of two fruits can be expected for him: either gnosis right here & now, or—if there be any remnant of clinging-sustenance—non-return.

The reality is very few of us is totally sincere in wanting to do the practice as diligently or consistently as requested by the Buddha. In the [Sedaka Sutta](https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/SN/SN47_20.html), the Buddha give an analogy of what it will be like for someone who truly practise in earnest. In the sutra, an executioner with a raised sword follows a convict as they make their way through a crowded marketplace. The convict is holding a bowl of oil filled to the brim. The instructions to the executioner were should the convict spilled even a drop of oil; the executioner will chop off the convict’s head. Meanwhile, a beauty queen is singing and dancing in the crowded marketplace. Will the convict be distracted?

Similarly, a practitioner is expected to fill their mind to the brim with mindfulness (like the bowl of oil). They are not to lower even a drop of their mindfulness throughout each waking moment. Imagine as we are practising, Taylor Swift is performing besides us. She calls out our name....where is our mind now?

Perhaps, we may feel that the Buddha’s demands are unrealistic and unachievable. Honestly, I can’t answer if it is reasonable to expect an ordinary lay person to attain Enlightenment. Reason is because I haven’t truly, honestly and sincerely even attempted to do the practice as requested by the Buddha....maybe we should at least try once?

Comment: she is everywhere like god it seems

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to understand you are inside a giant game. A game that'll last at least half a dozen decades for an average human. Normally, a computer game could be turned on and off at will. But this game cannot be paused. We are forced to play it whether we like it or not. If the game provided easy choices, either play it or not your choice, it would make things much more easier. But, we're forced to deal with samsara to extract energy out of it for our survival. We have to deal with `humans` because we have no other choice. Even those esteemed monks and their monasteries are built upon the backs of people in samasara.

Nibbana shows up on the horizon when the game of life has reached its ceiling. You understand deeply what the game of life has to offer. Enjoyment in food, movies, games, beautiful scenery, beautiful faces, etc for a couple dozen of starting years and then it's groundhog day all days after.

As with any game, whether we reach nibbana or not depends on how long we keep enjoying the game, 10 years, 20 years, 30 years, maybe never. Well, blessed are those who find enjoyment day in day out until death. However, for those of us unlucky ones, we seek freedom from the bondage that is the game of life. We are disenchanted with the forms, feeling, wearied of consciousness. We want to reach a place we can just pause the game.

Let's be patient. It may seem far but it isn't. Things will start to unravel itself if we keep on surviving. Just like river flows downstream, the mind will understand the game more and more, find the limits and seek something beyond.

Answer (score 2):

*how on earth is an ordinary lay person supposed to attain it?*

By not grasping.

> [MN24:10.9](https://suttacentral.net/mn24/en/sujato#mn24:10.9): “The purpose of leading the spiritual life under the Buddha is extinguishment by not grasping.”

Grasping at Nibbana won't get us anywhere simply because grasping is NOT the point of the Noble Eightfold Path. Grasping at Nibbana would be Wrong View.

> [MN117:6.1](https://suttacentral.net/mn117/en/sujato#mn117:6.1): And what is right view?
> [MN117:6.2](https://suttacentral.net/mn117/en/sujato#mn117:6.2): Right view is twofold, I say.
> [MN117:6.3](https://suttacentral.net/mn117/en/sujato#mn117:6.3): There is right view that is accompanied by defilements, has the attributes of good deeds, and ripens in attachment.
> [MN117:6.4](https://suttacentral.net/mn117/en/sujato#mn117:6.4): And there is right view that is noble, undefiled, transcendent, a factor of the path.

Right view is the start of the path. Start walking and let go of "are we there yet?"

Answer (score 1):

The Pali canon is full of examples where a lay follower has attained Nirvana.

Based on actions your past lives it will be decided how many lives you will take to attain Nirvana or how far or near you are to attain Nirvana. We all are at different levels when it comes to attaining. We are all on our own journey to Nirvana. E.g. in your past life, you might have reached the state of once-returner so you might attain in this very life. As opposed to some monks in monasteries who have reached just stream entry. So don't think that just because you are a lay follower and not some monk you cannot attain Nirvana in this very life.

Further to this practise mindfulness as far as possible throughout the day. Associate yourself with some sangha, with friends who are into meditation. Practice witnessing awareness.

Read about the books on meditation and mindfulness. I will suggest you the book 'Mindfulness Bliss and beyond' by Ajahn Brahm, for a detailed look into how to practice mindfulness and other meditative states.

Try to attain 'Silent present moment awareness' which is mindfulness of the present moment.

Also, keep in touch with all those who have attained Nirvana and are teaching on YouTube like Eckhart Tolle. Sometimes their insights help along with the Buddha's insights to progress along the path.

You never know maybe you are closer to attaining Nirvana than all of us on this site.

Also, diligently practice making good karma.

You can also go to a 10 days Vipassana retreat to get a feel of monks life.

Answer (score 0):

**1) practices consistently for 7 days?**

Only if

1. [ you have normal level **intellect**(or higher) ] +
2. [ will to give your **100%** in all 7 days(which a lot of people lack) ] +
3. [ **learn** what to do in that 7 days **correctly** before starting(also a lot of people don't get) ] +
4. [ **enough good karma**(Not have done very bad karma in this or old(near past) lives) ]

.

**2) there are thousands of monks who live in monasteries and practice all day everyday who aren't enlightened**?

There are some enlightened. (like 0.1% of all monks/my guess)

But every other monk lacks one or many of the above 4 variables. (like 75%/my guess)

Some monks don't wish to be enlightened in this life also. (like 25%/my guess)
You may ask why? That's because they want to become Buddha himself, Pasebudu or special position of a future Buddha's followers.

**3) "So are you saying we are all stuck here forever?".**

That's **the problem**. (we are all stuck here forever)
Buddha teaches us how to be **free from it forever**.

**4) How on earth is an ordinary lay person supposed to attain it?**

Are you saying, you want to eat the mango but you don't want to touch it?

Stop being "an ordinary lay person"(as you said) and learn and do it yourself.

How would you expect to go somewhere(in normal life) without fulfilling the below procedure?

1. You/anyone needs some intellect to find the road(look at map, read the map, ask people, decide directions)
2. Some will to go until you find the destination you wanted (even your feet heart, go against stopping)
3. Learn how to read maps, find directions, and language to speak to people on the way to ask directions

See. **The above steps are essential.**

**Don't take this personally. That's just the truth for everyone.**

There's correct(**Theravada**) Buddha's teaching still existing in countries like **Sri Lankan/Ceylon**.

Thanks . Any questions are welcome. ☸.

Comment: I mean, what is wrong with this answer? Are there any issue? Just ask about it in comments. Not down vote.

Comment: Don't take it personally. I believe there is a habitual down-voter in this forum who is also a disbeliever in karma. They don't understand their habits are a result of their karma and lack the wisdom and virtues to break free of their karmic prison. I think this answer is truthful and relevant.

Answer (score 0):

From my own understanding one does not need to be ordained to reach nibbana, I mean the Buddha was not ordained before he found it. Though as far as I know in the scriptures, only one non ordained (lay) person reached nibbana in Buddhas life time. I cannot remember the source but he was a naked ascetic.

It's as if one was seeking and able to reach nibbana, one would naturally find the dharma and to encompass oneself in the dharma and make the right conditions to practice earnestly, one would find the sangha, become ordained and lead a homeless life.
Like a natural progression.

Essentially the only difference between a lay and an ordained person is the vows that lead to strict conduct and going forth into the homeless life. Meaning they have the time and external conditions to be able to support the practice.

As we are not ready for it, we are still clinging to samsara, are still seeking pleasure etc so we are still lay people, still doing mundane things rather than spending our entire time on the path.

Comment: Not an ordained Buddhist monk, but the Buddha wasn't a lay-person -- already a homeless wanderer, a former student of others, a recluse, meditating full-time, etc.

Comment: He was a homeless ascetic, a mendicant, there was no such thing as an ordained person (in Buddhism) at the time as he hadn't even created such a status, but in contrast to what is now Buddhism as a religion, there are only 3 distinctions, well maybe 4, a lay person, an angrika, a postulate (novice) and a fully ordained member of the sangha. Buddha was a lay person, though we could argue that he was an angrika.

Answer (score 0):

The Pali Suttas appear to contain no examples of laypeople attaining Arahantship. It appears the highest attainment in the Pali Suttas for a layperson is non-return. Refer to this link: [*The Jhānas and the Lay Disciple According to the Pāli Suttas*: Bhikkhu Bodhi](https://budsas.net/ebud/ebdha267.pdf).

The Satipatthana Sutta refers to attaining Arahantship in a week (seven days) however the Satipatthana Sutta (for various overt reasons) appears to be a fake composition and never spoken by the Buddha.

Comment: I didn't realize Satipatthana Sutta was dubiously credible. It's the most popular Theravada Sutta (I think), which makes that pretty shocking to me. I'm curious as to what those overt reasons for fraudulence are, so that I can attempt to discern the authenticity of that sutta.

Comment: A post about this matter is at this link: https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/39180/8157

Answer (score -1):

In Theravada, there are four stages of liberation: stream entry, once-returner, never-returner and arahant (the perfected one).

For a lay person, it is unlikely that he or she can achieve anything beyond stream entry. Even stream entry is difficult to reach.

[AN 10.92](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an10/an10.092.than.html) lists out the criteria for stream entry:

- Five forms of fear and animosity are stilled (basically the five precepts)
- Four factors of stream entry
- Rightly seen and rightly ferreted out the noble method (dependent origination)

And also:

> “Sāriputta, they speak of a ‘factor of stream-entry’. What is a factor
> of stream-entry?”
>
> “Sir, the factors of stream-entry are associating with good people,
> listening to the true teaching, proper attention, and practicing in
> line with the teaching.”
> [SN 55.5](https://suttacentral.net/sn55.5/en/sujato?layout=plain&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin)

The best that a lay person can hope to do is try to practise and fulfill the above, especially the five precepts and the four factors of stream entry.

> At one time the Buddha was staying near Varanasi, in the deer park at
> Isipatana. Then the **lay follower Dhammadinna, together with five
> hundred lay followers**, went up to the Buddha, bowed, sat down to one
> side, and said to him:
>
> “May the Buddha please advise and instruct us. It will be for our
> lasting welfare and happiness.”
>
> “So, Dhammadinna, you should train like this: ‘From time to time we
> will undertake and dwell upon the discourses spoken by the Realized
> One that are deep, profound, transcendent, dealing with emptiness.’
> That’s how you should train yourselves.”
>
> “Sir, we live at home with our children, using sandalwood imported
> from Kāsi, wearing garlands, perfumes, and makeup, and accepting gold
> and money. It’s not easy for us to undertake and dwell from time to
> time upon the discourses spoken by the Realized One that are deep,
> profound, transcendent, dealing with emptiness. Since we are
> established in the five training rules, please teach us further.”
>
> “So, Dhammadinna, you should train like this: ‘We will have
> experiential confidence in the Buddha … the teaching … the Saṅgha …
> And we will have the ethical conduct loved by the noble ones … leading
> to immersion.’ That’s how you should train yourselves.”
>
> “Sir, these four factors of stream-entry that were taught by the
> Buddha are found in us, and we embody them. For we have experiential
> confidence in the Buddha … the teaching … the Saṅgha … And we have the
> ethical conduct loved by the noble ones … leading to immersion.”
>
> **“You’re fortunate, Dhammadinna, so very fortunate! You have all
> declared the fruit of stream-entry.”**
> [SN 55.53](https://suttacentral.net/sn55.53/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=plain&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=true&script=latin)

Comment: So are you saying we are all stuck here forever?

Comment: @Saddhā It's like a man who has his spectacles placed on top of his head but he looks for it everywhere. You cannot say for sure how long he has to look for it, but one day, if he is lucky, he will find it on top of his head. If he is not lucky, he will never find it. In the suttas, some people just listen attentively to one discourse of the Buddha, and instantly attain stream entry at the end of it.